# Specify server in IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup in Azure DevOps YAML pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to specify a server name in the IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0 in a Pipeline in Azure DevOps.

**Question 1**

Is there an alternative for the `YAML` (vs Classic / graphic designer) pipeline?

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines):

```
# This task is supported on **classic release pipelines only**.
# Use the classic designer to add and configure this task in a classic release pipeline.
# See the following Inputs section for details on the inputs that this task supports.
```

**Question 2**

Is there a way to pass in a server in the Pipeline (I've tried Releases which runs on a server in the Deployment Group

I'm aware of the `powershell` [script](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup.ps1) behind it.

Under the [IISApplicationPool](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/198118169c963ee4375354174f8072a7623663b2/Tasks/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroupV0/IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup.ps1#L117-L118) section, there is:

```
Set-IISApplicationPool -actionIISApplicationPool $actionIISApplicationPool -appPoolName $appPoolName -startStopRecycleAppPoolName $startStopRecycleAppPoolName -dotNetVersion $dotNetVersion `
                -pipeLineMode $pipeLineMode -appPoolIdentity $appPoolIdentity -appPoolUsername $appPoolUsername -appPoolPassword $appPoolPassword -appCmdCommands $appCmdCommands
```

I don't see the option / switch to pass in the server

Thank you

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup-has-no/1415449?q=IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/YAML-release-pipeline-deploy-stage-not-d/10053723?q=IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup&sort=newest